# Благословить наказать

Tags: этимология, глаголы

Сохранил ли в русском языке глагол "благословить" имевшееся ранее в старославянском двойное глагольное управление наподобие глагола наказать ("что/кому" и "кого/чем")?

Кому
по образу божию сътвори его, мужа и жену сътвори ихъ, и благослови **имъ**.

Кого
И благослови **ихъ** богъ глаголя, раститеся и множитеся и наполните землю, и обладаите ею.

Comment: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/bts/ словарь в помощь.